# power8 assembly code with shared build issue with save and restore of TOC

Tags: powerpc

I have the following assembly code

```
        .machine power8
        .abiversion 2
        .section        ".toc","aw"
        .section        .text
        GLOBAL(myfunc)
myfunc:
        stdu 1,-240(1)
        mflr 0
        std  0, 0*8(1)
        mfcr 8
        std  8, 1*8(1)
        std  2, 2*8(1)
        # Save all non-volatile registers R14-R31
        std  14, 4*8(1)
        ...
        # Save all the non-volatile FPRs
        ...
        stwu 1, -48(1)
        bl function_call
        nop
        addi 1, 1, 48
        ld   0, 0*8(1)
        mtlr 0
        ld  8, 1*8(1)
        ld  2, 2*8(1)
        ...
        # epilogue, restore stack frame
```

This works fine with static build but shared build gives segmentation fault in 
 `00000157.plt_call.__tls_get_addr_opt@@GLIBC_2.22`, should the shared build be handled differently in power8 w.r.t TOC?

Comment: is the `function_call` symbol in a local object, or a library?

Answer (score 1):

The calling convention is the same between POWER 8 and previous processors. However, there has been changes with regards to the TOC pointer (`r2`) handling between ABIv1 and ABIv2.

In ABIv2, the caller does not establish the TOC pointer in `r2`; the called function should do this for global entry points (ie, where the TOC pointer may not be the same as that used in the callee). To do this, ABIv2 functions will have a prologue that sets `r2`:

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   00 00 4c 3c     addis   r2,r12,0
   4:   00 00 42 38     addi    r2,r2,0
```

- this depends on `r12` containing the address of the function's global entry point (those 0 values will be replaced with actual offsets at final link time).

I don't see any code setting `r12` appropriately in your example. Are you sure you're complying with the v2 ABI there?

The ABIv2 spec is available here: https://members.openpowerfoundation.org/document/dl/576 Section 2.3.2 will be the most relevant for this issue.

Comment: Yes I do have ```        addis   2, 12, 0
        addi    2, 2, 0``` before setting the stack size `stdu 1,-240(1)`. But still getting the same segmentation fault. function_call is external C function

Comment: Where are those `addis` instructions? does `function_call` conform to ABIv2 as well?

Comment: I did add `myfunc:
.LCF1:
0:      addis 2,12,.TOC.-.LCF1@ha
        addi 2,2,.TOC.-.LCF1@l
        .localentry     myfunc,.-myfunc`

Comment: I even tried with `myfunc:
              addis 2, 12, 0
              addi   2, 2, 0` as you had suggested

Comment: The function_call does confirm to ABIv2. The code works fine and passes all tests when built with `--enable-static --disable-shared`. It fails with segmentation fault with `--enable-shared --disable-static`

Comment: The setup of `r2` doesn't matter for your function, it doesn't use the toc at all. However, you need to ensure that the *called* functions are passed the correct state, otherwise their toc references may be invalid. It doesn't look like you're setting up `r12`for the called functions. This would explain the difference between shared and static, which may cause different linkages.

Comment: I could get this working for power8. How does the calling convention differ in power4?

Comment: @Ramya: it doesn't differ between processors - the calling convention is a property of your toolchain (and code that you're linking with), not the processor.